# I have accidentally cleared contents from /var/log/messages and now log messages are not getting logged on my RHEL7.6 OS

Tags: linux, logging, rhel7

On my RHEL 7.6 OS system, I have accidentally cleared contents from `/var/log/messages` and now logs are getting logged.

I have tried restarting the rsyslog using `service rsyslog restart`, After executing this command in `/var/log/messages` file below messages got generated. Even though in generated message it says `Started System Logging Service` still logs not getting logged. please suggest how to make this right.

```
Feb 10 12:15:31 dragon systemd: Stopping System Logging Service...
Feb 10 12:15:31 dragon rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-34.el7" x-pid="5588" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Feb 10 12:15:31 dragon systemd: Stopped System Logging Service.
Feb 10 12:15:31 dragon systemd: Starting System Logging Service...
Feb 10 12:15:31 dragon rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-34.el7" x-pid="20937" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Feb 10 12:15:31 dragon systemd: Started System Logging Service.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for RHEL7 OS, we need to use `systemctl restart rsyslog` command where `service rsyslog restart` can be use on RHEL6 servers.

To test command worked fine, you can try with `logger -i "New log is my command reaching.."`  if the statement gets logged on `\var\log\messages` then it has restarted logging back.

Answer (score -1):

I deliberately ran > /var/log/messages to clear the file as it was rather large. No logging until I ran systemctl restart rsyslog as mentioned above. It's working fine now.